# createParamDecorator VS CanActivate in Nestjs for authorization

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I'm trying to authorize users based on their permissions. Is there any difference in functionality between using createParamDecorator and CanActivate method?

```
export const GetUser = createParamDecorator((data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) : User => {

  const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  const user  = request.user;
  const permissions = user.permissions
  for(var i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++){
      if(permissions[i].name === data)
         return user;
  }
  throw new NotFoundException()})
```

Comment: I don't think they aren't equivalent at all. With `createParamDecorator` you creates a decorator factory. With nestjs's guards you define whether or not an icoming request should go further

Comment: With the custom decorator, It's possible to access req and user and also permissions. so you can authorize user based on permissions via createParamDecorator.

Comment: You're right but I've never see this approach. Could you please show us an example of using `createParamDecorator` for this?

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are absolutely not equivalent approaches, and should not be considered as such. The `createParamDecorator` is supposed to be an easy way to tell Nest how to inject a custom value (e.g. `req.user` instead of having to do `@Req() { user }`). It was never meant to be used for authorization, and while you can, it will most likely lead to very weird stack traces.

Guards, on the other hands, were **made** for authentication and authorization of the request. You can set metadata on a handler (e.g. what roles are allowed), read them with the `Reflector`, and then apply the conditional logic of if the request is valid or not. You're also able to use dependency injection on guards to add things like your database connection and get a full user from the database from an ID, which isn't possible in the `createParamDecorator`.

Lastly, in guards you can throw any error you want, or you can return `false` and get back a 403 by Nest's design.

> Is there any difference in functionality...?

As mentioned, the dependency injection. It's also easier to test guards, in my opinion. But that's me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In createParamDecorator you can also throw whatever you want, but what do you mean by weird stack traces?